# Strange behavior about CreateProcess

Tags: win32-process

I intent to encapsulate a function to execute a command with C++.
code as below:

```
std::string ExecuteCommand(const std::string& command)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    HANDLE hReadPipe, hWritePipe;

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    if (!CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &saAttr, 0)) {
        return "";
    }


    if (!SetHandleInformation(hReadPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        return "";
    }

    DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT;
    if (!SetNamedPipeHandleState(hReadPipe, &dwMode, NULL, NULL)) {
        CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
        CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
        return "";
    }

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = hWritePipe;
    si.hStdOutput = hWritePipe;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)command.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        std::cout << ::GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
        CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
        return "";
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    CHAR chBuffer[4096];
    std::string output;

    while (ReadFile(hReadPipe, chBuffer, sizeof(chBuffer) - 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL) != FALSE) {
        if (dwBytesRead == 0) {            
            break;
        }
        chBuffer[dwBytesRead] = '\0';
        output += chBuffer;
    }    

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
    CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
    return output;
}
```

and then, i try write some unit test for this function.

1. std::cout << ExecuteCommand("ipconfig /all") << std::endl;
2. std::cout << ExecuteCommand("netsh mbn show interface");
3. std::cout << ExecuteCommand("logman") << std::endl;
4. std::cout << ExecuteCommand("logman /?") << std::endl;
   case 1: OK
   case 2: The following command was not found: mbn show interface.
   case 3: freeze，blocking in function WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
   case 4: freeze, blocking in function WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

i've tried quoting the parameters, passing an absulute path, noting helps.
Test environment:
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, console appliation

help function for execute commands